# Join multiple Shape Keys into one for Sequence Animation

Tags: shape-keys

I know this has been addressed before by I am still unable to accomplish it: 
My goal is to make each rectangle either disappear or have vertices collapse in one side so they don't show.

In other words: If I move the shape key value box starting at zero, the rectangles start to disappear from the right to the left, one by one in order all the way to the left end. I don't need keyframe animation, only shape keys because of my project.

I'm so sorry as I don't really have much experience with Blender and I don't want anyone to waste their time with me, but I need a step by step tutorial if possible. This place is awesome and everyone benfits from it. I love how a lot of people have a big heart. I will be vey thankful beforehand. 
THANK YOU AGAIN

[image]

Here is a link to gdrive https://drive.google.com/open?id=1stlHTDvSP-EKyKlp7kRy1sEfbs4oHwBO

Comment: There is no way you can remove geometry with a shape key... just offset them to a new location. You are very specific in how you want to solve the problem. I don't think that you can do it this way. I would try to do this in a material instead where you move a mask and make in transparent.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Files on other services tend to "vanish", thus rendering your question and possible answers practically useless in the future. Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135116/edit) below your question to add the link to your question.

Comment: My idea is just to collapse the vertices..that would be enough. Making each rectangle very small wd be enough.